# Opening the apps under settings using code

Tags: android

When we go into settings, there is a list item named apps on clicking which we can see All the apps. Also there are tabs for Downloaded, Running and Cached apps.

My goal is to open this apps page with default to the first tab (All).

Searched but couldn't find the code for the same. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS);
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

For more information go to: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html

Comment: @Sandeep where is your screen snap?